# About the scope of impact due to Facebook Graph API rate limit

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I want to know the extent of the throttling effect when FacebookGraphAPI's rate limit is exceeded.
Create a Facebook app from Meta for Developers,
We have implemented "Facebook login function" and "article posting function to Facebook page".
If one is throttled due to API rate limits, will the other function be throttled as well?

I am aware that in the official documentation, rate limits are set for each access token.
However, the relationship between rate limits and access tokens does not seem to be mentioned.
If anyone knows, I would appreciate it if you could let me know.

■Premise
The "Facebook login function" uses user access tokens.
The "article posting function to Facebook page" uses page access tokens.
Recognize that rate limits are set for each access token.

■Official document
・API rate limit
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/rate-limiting

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/rate-limiting#pages should clarify things enough already, or in what aspect doesn't it?

Comment: Official documentation doesn't seem to include the range of influence of each rate limit.
For example, if the "user access token" is rate limited,
I am concerned that "page access token" issued by the same app may also be affected.